# Android TallyServer communication

Tags: java, android, erp

Hi I am working with android.I am trying to create a tally android app. How can I connect android with tally server. How can I get/post data between tally server. I searched a lot and didn't find a solution. Please help me with your suggestions.Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

in android if you want to send HttpRequest , use the [Apache http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506039/957654) , it describe the usage of the library.

it doesnt matter if its tally server , or what ever , you just need to provide the link for the server in your case like the following :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://tallyentrprise.com"));
```

Hope that Helps .